# order data.table along numeric column puttint special Value (residual category) of other column last

Tags: r, data.table

is there a possibility to order a data.table along a numeric column while putting a special row (residual category) last (based on label of another column)?

```
DT <- data.table (a =c("a", "sd", "set", "c", "s", "REST", "sde", "de"), 
              b=c(5,1:4, 2.5, 1:2))
```

Expected Output would be something like

```
      a   b
1:   sd 1.0
2:  sde 1.0
3:  set 2.0
4:   de 2.0
5:    c 3.0
6:    s 4.0
7:    a 5.00
8: REST 2.5
```

I've put one answer below, but I wonder if there is one possibility without rbind. This is complicated, and I suppose this will also copy the whole data.table ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass expressions to `order`.

```
DT[order(a=="REST", b)] # internally optimised to use data.table's fast ordering
```

If you would like to use `setorder` instead (which reorders by reference):

```
DT[, tmp := a == "REST"]
setorder(DT, tmp, b)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
rbind(DT[a!="REST"][order(DT[a!="REST",b])],
      DT[which.max(DT$a=="REST")])
```

gives

```
       a   b
 1:   sd 1.0
 2:  sde 1.0
 3:  set 2.0
 4:   de 2.0
 5:    c 3.0
 6:    s 4.0
 7:    a 5.0
 8: REST 2.5
```